# Compare the output of 2 exe files for integers i=1 to 2^64

Tags: shell, compare

I want to compare the output of two exe files yourExe1 and yourExe2 for the same input (integers i= 1, 2, .. 2^64 ). I wrote the file myTest1.sh below.

It would be possible to make the program faster?.

Thank you for your help!. JJV

myTest1.sh

```
i=0
echo INICIO $(date) >> out1.txt
echo nStart   $i >> out1.txt
while [ $i -le 4294967295 ]
do
    i=` expr $i + 1`
    if [ "$(./myExe1 $i)" != "$(./myExe2 $i)" ]
    then
    echo For $i we get different restuls. >>out1.txt
    fi

done
echo endNumber: $i >> out1.txt
echo $(date) >> out1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that can optimised.

```sh
i=` expr $i + 1`
```

can be written as `i=$((i + 1))`

```sh
echo For $i we get different restuls. >>out1.txt
```

can placed outside of the while loop as

```sh
while ...
do
...
done > out1.txt
```

---

All of these will avoid unnecessary overhead of subshells / redirections.